# Java sieves theorem prime numbers array/methods

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm trying to return prime numbers only from my function to my main but java keeps telling me to create the local variable findPrimes even though I did, I cant seem to spot the problem:

```
public static int[] primesOnly(int[] array, int N)
    {   
        int primes = 0;
        int i = 2;
        while(i < array.length)
        {
            if(array[i] == 0)
            {
                int multiple = 2*i;
                while(multiple < N)
                {
                    array[multiple] = 1;
                    multiple = multiple + i;
                }

            }
            if(array[i] == 0)
            {   
                System.out.print(i + " ");
                primes++;
            }

            i++;
        }
        while(i < array.length)
        {
            int[] justPrimes = new int[primes];
            for(int index = 0; index < primes; index++)
            {
                if(array[i] == 0)
                    justPrimes[index] = i;
            }

            i++;
        }
        return justPrimes;
    }
```

Comment: Move declaration of `justPrimes` out side of second while loop.

Answer (score 0):

`justPrimes` is defined within the scope of your `while` loop. That means that you cannot reference it outside the loop. Simply move the declaration outside the loop:

```
    int[] justPrimes = new int[primes];
    while(i < array.length)
    {
        for(int index = 0; index < primes; index++)
        {
            if(array[i] == 0)
                justPrimes[index] = i;
        }

        i++;
    }
    return justPrimes;
```

As a second note, it does not seem efficient to loop through the data twice. It would seem to make more sense to accumulate your prime numbers on the first pass through and then copy into an appropriately sized `int[]` on completion.